# How to find first value from an array column which matches a substring in a different column? PySpark

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, list, pyspark

I'm trying to select the first instance of an element in an array column which matches a substring in a different column, and then create a different column with the selected element, like this:

| col_a | col_b |
| --- | --- |
| [AB1 2Z,CD3 4Y,AB5 6X] | AB |
| [GH7 8W,EF9 0V,EF1 2U] | EF |
| [IJ3 4T,KL5 6S] | KL |

Returning this output column, including the two above:

| col_c |
| --- |
| AB1 2Z |
| EF9 0V |
| KL5 6S |

I've tried this with `getItem()`:

```
df = df.withColumn('col_c', df.getItem(filter(col_a, i -> startsWith(I, 'col_b')))[0]"))
```

But I'm getting an analysis exception that the `getItem` function isn't defined, so I'm not sure if this would work without that exception, or what I need to do to solve the exception.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a udf to filter for the pattern you want:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Example") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample DataFrame
data = [(['AB1 2Z','CD3 4Y','AB5 6X'], 'AB'),
        (['GH7 8W','EF9 0V','EF1 2U'], 'EF'),
        (['IJ3 4T','KL5 6S'], 'KL')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['col_a', 'col_b'])

# Define a UDF to find the first matching element
find_matching_element_udf = udf(lambda arr, substr: next((x for x in arr if substr in x), None), StringType())

# Apply the UDF to find the first matching element
df = df.withColumn("matching_element", find_matching_element_udf(col("col_a"), col("col_b")))

df.show(truncate=False)


Output:
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+-----+----------------+
|               col_a|col_b|matching_element|
+--------------------+-----+----------------+
|[AB1 2Z, CD3 4Y, ...|   AB|          AB1 2Z|
|[GH7 8W, EF9 0V, ...|   EF|          EF9 0V|
|    [IJ3 4T, KL5 6S]|   KL|          KL5 6S|
+--------------------+-----+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This code runs but when I try to show the df in the console I get an error: 'an error occurred while calling 0242.showString' - any ideas? Cheers

Comment: The error is not sufficient enough. I might need to look at your code to see.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
df = (
    df
    .withColumn('col_c', f.expr('filter(col_a, element -> startswith(element, col_b))')[0])
)
```

If you must only use PySpark transformations:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('col_c', f.element_at(f.filter(f.col('col_a'), lambda x : f.startswith(x, f.col('col_b'))), 1))
)
```

and the output is:

```
+------------------------+-----+------+                                         
|col_a                   |col_b|col_c |
+------------------------+-----+------+
|[AB1 2Z, CD3 4Y, AB5 6X]|AB   |AB1 2Z|
|[GH7 8W, EF9 0V, EF1 2U]|EF   |EF9 0V|
|[IJ3 4T, KL5 6S]        |KL   |KL5 6S|
+------------------------+-----+------+
```